# BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

For some specific reason I need to edit the 2.6.32.65 Linux kernel to read sectors from the hard disk to a specific location, before pages are allocated in memory. for example in function `do_generic_file_read` in `mm/filemap.c` I do the following:

```
myRet = mapping->a_ops->readpage(filp,myPage);          //Added
Function_Operates_On_MyPage();                          //Added

page = page_cache_alloc_cold(mapping);
if (!page) {
    desc->error = -ENOMEM;
    goto out;
}
```

and then later the function actually reads the sector again to the allocated page as follows:

```
    error = mapping->a_ops->readpage(filp, page);
```

Of course this is not optimum, but I only need it for testing purposes so it doesn't matter. now this works fine and does what I want it to do. It also works fine in multiple other locations, except in `__do_page_cache_readahead` in `mm/readahead.c`. It looks like the following:

```
for (page_idx = 0; page_idx < nr_to_read; page_idx++) {
    pgoff_t page_offset = offset + page_idx;

    if (page_offset > end_index)
        break;

    rcu_read_lock();
    page = radix_tree_lookup(&mapping->page_tree, page_offset);
    rcu_read_unlock();
    if (page)
        continue;

    myRet = mapping->a_ops->readpage(filp,myPage);          //Added
    Function_Operates_On_Mypage();                          //Added
    page = page_cache_alloc_cold(mapping);
    if (!page)
        break;
    page->index = page_offset;
    list_add(&page->lru, &page_pool);
    if (page_idx == nr_to_read - lookahead_size)
        SetPageReadahead(page);
    ret++;
}

if (ret)
    read_pages(mapping, filp, &page_pool, ret);
```

It calls `read_pages` which actually reads the sectors again to their allocated pages. now `read_pages` to my knowledge does the same as I do:

```
for (page_idx = 0; page_idx < nr_pages; page_idx++) {
    struct page *page = list_to_page(pages);
    list_del(&page->lru);
    if (!add_to_page_cache_lru(page, mapping,
                page->index, GFP_KERNEL)) {
        mapping->a_ops->readpage(filp, page);
    }
    page_cache_release(page);
}
ret = 0;
```

however the `readpage` works fine in `read_pages` but when I add it inside  `__do_page_cache_readahead` it causes the error `BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffea0df0668018`. the only difference between both line is the page that gets the data. which worked fine with me in other cases. why does this happen? how to fix it?

**Edit 1**

`readpage` is a pointer to function `mpage_readpage` in file `fs/mpage.c` which calls `do_mpage_readpage` in the same file. using `printk`s I was able to find that the fault actually happens at the first line of `do_mpage_readpage` which is as follows:

```
struct inode *inode = page->mapping->host;
```

the problem is that the page I use to read from the hard disk is marked reserved on startup (I don't want this location to be allocated to any process!). So I'm not sure what `page->mapping` would be. I'm guessing this is what is causing the error, but I don't know how to fix that! I'm also not sure how it did work on other locations, maybe because `readpage`  pointed to functions other than `mpage_readpage`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot of struggle with that, I found that my error was really stupid and straightforward. I just used an invalid page address (actually forgot to convert between pfn and page at some step). Once I solved that it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer would've been more useful if it had actually explained the issue, showed some code, etc. This response won't help anyone else coming here to see it.

Answer (score 2):

From your codes, I guessed the error occurred in `page = page_cache_alloc_cold(mapping);`.I have googled it: the `page_cache_alloc_cold` used for allocating a new page when it did not found the wanted page in cache.But if you call the function frequently， the kernel will oops because the memory provided for kernel is so small ! The problems I have meet ever, my solution was allocating pages in advance in your module_init() function（Pre-allocation）.It would avoid to calling `page_cache_alloc_cold` frequently. I hope this will help you.

Comment: This is so old, I even forgot about it. What you're talking about would really make sense. Except that I don't do it that frequently. In fact I allocate the page in a specific location, do something with it, free it. I do the same every time. So basicly I only occupy just one page for all these allocations.

Comment: After a lot of struggle with that, I found that my error was really stupid. That I didn't even want to post an answer here! I just used an invalid page address (actually forgot to convert between pfn and page at some step). Once I solved that it worked like a charm.